# Extract subject and sender using python (imaplib)

Tags: python, email, imaplib, subject

I know there are some other posts out there, but i tried to use them but most of I couln´t make them run or they are simply to old. I hope there is someone that can help me.

I simply want to extract the subject and the sender of all **new emails** in my gmail account and set them von unread to read.

So far I just have the IMAP4 Example from the doc that gives me all my mails:

```
import imaplib

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('mymail@gmail.com', 'mypassword')
mail.list()
mail.select('inbox')

typ, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
for num in data[0].split():
   typ, data = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
   print ('Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, data[0][1]))
mail.close()

mail.logout()
```

So i need to add that i only want to have new mails & set them vom unread to read...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can study `RFC 2060` , `IMAP4.search()` and `IMAP4.store()` for the action.

```
# To list the unseen mail
result, data = mail.search(None, 'UNSEEN')

# Mark message as seen
for message in data[0].split():
   mail.store(message, '+FLAGS', '\\Seen')
```